# Magento 1.9: Get individual item options via SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, items

I'm having trouble to get individual item information from the shopping cart in Magento 1.9. as a little introduction: We're running a store which sells individual stickers for motorcycles and the customer has to make some specifications (like when the bike was built or how big the engine is).

[image]

I can see that this information are in the shopping card (ordered items) but I'm not able to find the right SOAP call to gather all this information. Is there anything I'm missing? 
I'm completely new with the Magento shop system and thankful for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance,

Tim